# wx.PyTextDataObject with drag and drop results in extra characters

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm using wx.PyTextDataObject as the data object for a drag and drop setup in wxPython.  When the user selects an item to drag the text is copied into a wx.PyTextDataObject and on drop the PyTextDataObject is copied into another (this is internal to wx, I don't control this).  The problem i'm having is that occasionally the copied text will contain a bit of garbage on the end.  It looks like some kind of buffer overflow problem in wx.

I've narrowed the problem down to the following example. The string in the example is from a use case that we've had problems with, drop one letter and there is no problem.

```
>>> import wx
>>> src = wx.PyTextDataObject(u'HR7984,HR8488,HR8893,HC7984,HC8488,HC8893,PO7984,PO8488,PO8893')
>>> dst = wx.PyTextDataObject()
>>> dst.SetData(src.GetDataHere())
True
>>> dst.GetText()
u'HR7984,HR8488,HR8893,HC7984,HC8488,HC8893,PO7984,PO8488,PO8893\u1f00x'
>>> src.GetText()
u'HR7984,HR8488,HR8893,HC7984,HC8488,HC8893,PO7984,PO8488,PO8893'
>>>
```

Has anyone experienced this bug before? Any ideas where the problem might be? If it's in wxWidgets I'd like to find a patch.

My setup is 
OSX, python 2.7, wx 2.8.12.1 (mac-unicode) Carbon.

Comment: thanks, probably specific to the mac port in that case. I'll try in in Linux.

Comment: doesn't reproduce in ubuntu either. Seems to be limited to OSX