# Unexpected characters appended at the end of text strings when using wx.TextDropTarget

Tags: python, drag-and-drop, wxpython

I am using wx.TextDropTarget to implement a drag and drop app where users can drag some text strings from a `ListCtrl` widget and drop them into `TextCtrl` widgets. One problem that I haven’t been able to figure out how to solve is that sometimes text strings dropped in `TextCtrl` widgets have random characters appended to the end (see screenshot below). This problem does not arise every single time – as you can see, “East of Eden” is displayed fine.

[image]

I am on OSX 10.10.5 and using wxPython 2.9.2.4-1. I am not sure if this problem can be reproduced on other platforms. A sample code is below.

```
import wx

from wx.lib.mixins.listctrl import ListCtrlAutoWidthMixin

class AutoWidthListCtrl(wx.ListCtrl, ListCtrlAutoWidthMixin):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.ListCtrl.__init__(self, parent, -1, style=wx.LC_REPORT)
        ListCtrlAutoWidthMixin.__init__(self)


class TextDropTarget(wx.TextDropTarget):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        wx.TextDropTarget.__init__(self)
        self.obj = obj

    def OnDropText(self, x, y, text):
        self.obj.WriteText(text)

    def OnDragOver(self, x, y, d):
        return wx.DragCopy


class MyApp(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__(parent, style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE, 
                            title=title, size=(500, 500))
        self.Panel = wx.Panel(self, size = (-1, -1))
        GridBagSizer = wx.GridBagSizer(5,5)

        #ListCtrl widget 
        self.Source = AutoWidthListCtrl(self.Panel)
        self.Source.Show()
        self.Source.InsertColumn(0, 'Book Titles')
        self.Source.InsertStringItem(0,'War and Peace')
        self.Source.InsertStringItem(0,'East of Eden')
        self.Source.InsertStringItem(0,'Pride and Prejudice')

        GridBagSizer.Add(self.Source, pos = (0, 0), span = (6, 1), 
                         flag = wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, border = 15)
        self.Panel.SetSizer(GridBagSizer)

        #Label for each TextCtrl widget
        AmericanNovel = wx.StaticText(self.Panel, label ="American Novel:")
        EnglishNovel = wx.StaticText(self.Panel, label = "British Novel:")
        RussianNovel = wx.StaticText(self.Panel, label = "Russian Novel:")      
        GridBagSizer.Add(AmericanNovel, pos = (0, 1), span = (1, 1), 
                         flag = wx.TOP, border = 10)
        GridBagSizer.Add(EnglishNovel, pos = (2, 1), span = (1, 1))
        GridBagSizer.Add(RussianNovel, pos = (4, 1), span = (1, 1))                      

        #TextCtrl widgets        
        self.Target1 = wx.TextCtrl(self.Panel, size = (240, -1), 
                                   style = wx.TE_READONLY)
        self.Target2 = wx.TextCtrl(self.Panel, size = (240, -1), 
                                   style = wx.TE_READONLY)
        self.Target3 = wx.TextCtrl(self.Panel, size = (240, -1), 
                                   style = wx.TE_READONLY)

        GridBagSizer.Add(self.Target1, pos = (1, 1), span = (1, 1))
        GridBagSizer.Add(self.Target2, pos = (3, 1), span = (1, 1))
        GridBagSizer.Add(self.Target3, pos = (5, 1), span = (1, 1))                      

        dt1 = TextDropTarget(self.Target1)
        dt2 = TextDropTarget(self.Target2)
        dt3 = TextDropTarget(self.Target3)
        self.Target1.SetDropTarget(dt1)
        self.Target2.SetDropTarget(dt2)
        self.Target3.SetDropTarget(dt3)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_BEGIN_DRAG, self.OnDragInit)

        GridBagSizer.AddGrowableCol(0)
        GridBagSizer.AddGrowableCol(1)        


    def OnDragInit(self, evt):
        text = self.Source.GetItemText(evt.GetIndex())
        tdo = wx.TextDataObject(text)
        tds = wx.DropSource(self.Source)
        tds.SetData(tdo)
        tds.DoDragDrop(True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    MainFrame = MyApp(None, title = "My App")
    MainFrame.Show()
    MainFrame.Centre()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Any pointer would be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have some sort of Chinese character set installed on your machine. Those "stray" characters look like they are a stab at a translation. Just a thought!

Comment: My computer can display Chinese, but the Mac OS is in English and I haven't installed anything special for Chinese. In other words, my computer can display Chinese out of the box

Answer (score 0):

Your code works on Linux.
The only thing that I can see, that differs from the standard examples, is your code:

```
tdo = wx.TextDataObject(text)
```

should be:

```
tdo = wx.PyTextDataObject(text)
```

although, with Linux it does not appear to matter.

EDIT:
First, see this link which appears to be related:
[wx.PyTextDataObject with drag and drop results in extra characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423197/wx-pytextdataobject-with-drag-and-drop-results-in-extra-characters)

Second:
As a work-around, try adding this after defining `text`

```
text = text.decode('iso-8859-1').encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

It's an attempt to remove the extraneous characters.
You could try printing them out as a raw string:

```
 print (repr(text))
```

Comment: Mmm, after changing `wx.TextDataObject` to `wx.PyTextDataObject`, the problem still persists. Maybe I should try it on a Windows machine to see if the same problem exists since I am making this actually for Windows.

Comment: Still doesn't work :-/ However, this problem cannot be reproduced on my Windows machine. Since the application is intended for Windows, I think I will for now overlook it.